# What does System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql) mean in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Could somebody please tell me what does `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand` and `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()` mean or does in vb.net?

Comment: Generally this site is for questions that you cannot so easily find the answer to at the top of a Google search.

Comment: this is not a tutorial site, rather it is intended for concrete answers to succint questions as thoroughly explained in [Ask]